# Programmicatically Adding Assets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

As part of CI build, I need to pull in a gigabyte of image content into my project file so it can be compiled into my appx.  The data and list of included files changes frequently, so it can't be included in the project beforehand.  Plus the sheer size would make our repo enormous.

Aside from cracking open the csproj itself and adding a bunch of xml to do this, is there a way to do this at build time?  Maybe something in pre-build that runs a command?

Comment: It sounds like maybe your images should not be bundled into the app, but accessed via a web service or something when needed.

Comment: What commands do you use to pull in the files? Have you tried to just run those as prebuild?

Comment: @GlenThomas That would be a good idea, but the app is the type of an app that is used when there is not network connectivity.

Comment: The user could download content when they do have connectivity (first run or regular sync) and then the app would store locally for offline access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I spent a ton of time on this, it turns out that simply using a pre-build step won't work, since you actually have to modify the csproj file.  Simply using MakeAppx won't work after compiling, the compilation process actually makes changes to your appxmanifest.

I ended up writing a tiny console app that does the work in a script before calling MSBuild.  I've included it below.

```
    private static void AddDirectoryToProject(string sourceDir, Project project)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir);


        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            var virtualStart = file.FullName.IndexOf("sourcebinaries");
            var virtualPath = file.FullName.Substring(virtualStart);

            project.AddItemFast("Content", virtualPath, new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CopyToOutputDirectory", "PreserveNewest")
            });

            Console.WriteLine(virtualPath);
        }

        foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            AddDirectoryToProject(subDir.FullName, project);
        }
    }
```